# How to get rid of rats in wall coming from old washer drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing

We moved our washer dryer from kitchen to garage couple of years ago. Now we have been hearing lots of scampering & squeaking from wall behind our new fridge location & inside adjoining bedroom wall.

We believe they are coming in thru the old washer drainage.

Any ideas on how to rid the rat & fix future entry

Answer (score 2):

1. Seal the entry hole - where was the washer drainage going, to daylight?  Rats can get into any crack that is larger than their skull size which is smaller than a quarter.  If you are talking about a mouse the hole size is unimaginably small.
2. Rat snap traps with peanut butter and lots of them.  Expect 50% to spring and not catch the rat.  Be prepared to deal with injured dying rats.
3. Rat poison in concrete shells to prevent other animals from accessing.  Be prepared for rats to die in your ceiling / walls and smell until they dry out.
4. Eliminate harborage around your property.  Rats like to move parallel to exterior walls, put the traps along their path.
5. Eliminate food sources in your yard.

Getting rid of rats is an arms race, so do everything at once.  Don't try #1 and then when that doesn't work add in #2.  Do 1-5 all at once.

Comment: There was a link posted to a trap called "walk the plank" last week, looked very effective for both rats and mice. I would Google that and watch the video.

Comment: Seal the entry hole by stuffing it with steel wool or blocking it with other material the rodents cannot chew through or dig around.  Since they are used to entry, they will try to defeat any blockage you put in place.